# How to filter an array of objects according to an attribute in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object, filter

I have an array of users object and I want to filter this array and delete all admin user according to the attribute Role.

[image]

the list of user is returned by a service  and I want to filter it in the OnInit function :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.accountService.getAll()
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(accounts => {
        console.log(accounts);
        this.accounts = accounts;
      });

  }
```

what kind of function can I use to do that ?

Comment: You may want to use `array.map`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily use the JS filter function. To get all non-admin users:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.accountService.getAll()
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(accounts => {
        console.log(accounts);
        this.accounts = accounts.filter((acct) => acct.role !== "Admin");
      });

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the filter operator:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.accountService.getAll()
      .pipe(
        first(), 
        filter(e => e.role !== 'Admin'))
      .subscribe(accounts => {
        console.log(accounts);
        this.accounts = accounts;
      });

  }
```